# How can I use OAuth with stateless REST API?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, oauth-2.0

When using Passport, a session is used to transfer the user information. This breaks the statelessness of my REST api. How can I use OAuth statelessly on a node/express server?

Answer (score 0):

Most APIs will use the `Authorization` header, but this is not *fundamentally different* from putting it in a cookie. Having an authentication token in either header doesn't really break any REST constraints.

The `Authorization` header is probably preferred unless you want your API to be usable by web browsers.

Comment: How can I verify the token which is created by OAuth 2.0

Comment: @Elbek that's a completely unrelated question.